# How to invoke Sms IOS and Android app in react Js Cordova?

Tags: reactjs, cordova, sms

I am trying to implement SMS and Call functionality in ReactJS Cordova. I am able to implement Call functionality by using the below logic.

```
 const callHandler = () => {
        const phoneNumber = `tel:${person?.mobileNumber}`;
        document.location.href = phoneNumber;
    };
```

But I am trying to implement invoking a native SMS app with some text message but unable to do it. Can someone help me on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this plugin to send sms - https://github.com/cordova-sms/cordova-sms-plugin

Here you need to use `intent:'INTENT'` in options to open the nativ SMS app.

Comment: Does it invoke both IOS and Android Native Apps with some default message

Comment: Yes, it works for both platform. Give it try.